# X can not be resolved to a variable in a for loop; Eclipse, Java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, int

I have just started working with Java and I am encountering an error for which reason I am not understanding. I have looked and have been unable to find my answer in another question, I do apologize if this is a repeat.

My code is:

```
public class Welcome {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("x\t x^2\t x^3");
    for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println("\t");
        System.out.println(x * x);
        System.out.println("\t");
        System.out.println(x * x * x);
    }
}
```

The code will run fine passing `x` for the first print, but in subsequent lines, `x * x` and `x * x * x` it is acting like `x` isn't defined. How can I get this code to run and what is the reasoning behind my error?

Thank you.

Comment: Add an opening brace to `for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++) {`, and a closing brace after `System.out.println(x * x * x); }`

Comment: Ahhhhhh, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to put range for if in here

it will only run the first println if begin and end curly braces is not specified

```
for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
{
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println("\t");
    System.out.println(x * x);
    System.out.println("\t");
    System.out.println(x * x * x);
}
```

**You're code**

```
for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++)    
    System.out.println(x);        //if you didn't specified the begin and end curly brace 
                                  //for range . this is the only line will work for it
    System.out.println("\t");     //from this line, x now is undefined
    System.out.println(x * x);    //*
    System.out.println("\t");     //*
    System.out.println(x * x * x);//until here
```